# standalone C++ preprocessor

Tags: preprocessor, c-preprocessor

I'm looking for a standalone C++ preprocessor. I'll use with another language, so there's no point in running through a full fledged compiler, but it's a very limited script language, so the #define and #if and other directives will help me a lot.

For example, I'd be writing a file like this:

```
#define DEBUG
do some stuff
#ifdef DEBUG
    show a message box or whatever
#endif
do some more stuff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something which fits my needs, [mcpp](http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/).
It's a simple to use preprocessor and supports output to other languages thanks to a command line switch.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [GNU C preprocessor?](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)

Comment: To be honest, that's not quite what I'm looking for. I don't want to install a full fledged compiler with libraries and headers and all that. Something much simpler and leaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look into [M4](http://www.gnu.org/s/m4/) preprocessor if you want some processing power greater than C/C++ preprocessor has. For example - M4 supports recursive macros, which isn't supported by C/C++ macro processor.